# Java: Method.invoke (this, args) NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I posted this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958036/java-read-from-config-file-efficiently-perform-tests-based-on-values) question, which basically amounts to an attempt to map Strings to functions in Java. I am trying to solve it by creating a `HashMap <String, Method>`, but every time I try to run Method.invoke (this, args), where args is an array of Objects corresponding to the parameters of Method, I get a `NullPointerException`. I declare the Methods in my `HashMap` as follows: `mypackage.MyClass.class.getMethod ("methodName", args)`, where `args` is an array of `Class` object corresponding to the parameters of `methodName`. I've been working on this for a couple of hours and I'm starting to get really frustrated. If anyone has any suggestions I would really appreciate it!

```
HashMap <String, Method> myMethods = new HashMap <String, Method> (); 
Class [] args = {param1.class, param2.class, param3.class}; 
myMethods.put ("aKey", mypackage.MyClass.class.getMethod ("aMethod", args)); 
Method thisTest = myTests.get (thisKey);
Object [] args1 = {param1, param2, param3};
String thisResult = (String) thisTest.invoke (this, args1); // NPE occurs in this line

Aug 14, 2012 10:37:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at mypackage.MyClass.myMethod (MyClass.java:61)
        at org.apache.jsp.myMethod_jsp._jspService(getZabbix_jsp.java:70)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:393)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:261)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:581)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Please, show us some code and the stack trace. It's really hard to tell what's going on.

Comment: Thank you for your help, everyone...clearly I'm having some trouble w/ the formatting on StackOverflow.

Comment: is "this" in the invoke() call an object of the correct type? In your case, it has to be a MyClass object

Comment: Yes, the methods and the code that runs Method.invoke belong to the same class.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Could it be that the `NullPointerException` occurs within the `aMethod` method?

Comment: No, @Jes, I don't think so...I did some troubleshooting where I tried to catch null values coming from the method, and that didn't seem to solve anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the population of `myTests` Map is not shown, it obviously doesn't contain the test method `thisTest` resulting in an NPE.

The first thing to do here is to inspect the contents of this Map to ensure that it contains the requested key.

Also, it's worth having a [guard clause](http://blog.mafr.de/2009/06/12/a-case-for-guard-clauses/) on `thisTest` before you attempt to invoke the method to prevent it blowing up.

Comment: Yes, the answer was a stupid syntax error on my part. Fixing it made everything work properly. Thank you everyone for your time and patience.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be **REALLY careful** when dealing with reflection.

The `Class` parameters MUST be an exact match to the `method` declaration you are searching for.

For example if you have a `method` that takes an `interface` of `MyAwesomeInterface` and you implement that `interface` in your `MyAwesomeImplementation`, you can't use the `class` reference of `MyAwesomeImplementation` when you look up the method.

For example

```
getClass().getMethod("doAwesomeness", new Class[] {MyAwesomeImplementation.class});
```

Won't work.  It requires `MyAwesomeInterface.class`

I put this little example together and it works fine

```
public String methodToBeInvoked(String value, int iValue) {

    return "You said " + value + " with " + iValue;

}

public MethodInvocation() {

    Map<String, Method> myMethods = new HashMap<String, Method>(25);
    try {

        Method method = getClass().getMethod("methodToBeInvoked", new Class[]{String.class, int.class});

        myMethods.put("invoke", method);

        System.out.println(myMethods.get("invoke").invoke(this, "Hello", 100));

    } catch (Exception exp) {

        exp.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

I suspect that the `class` parameters you are using to look up the method do not match the method declarations.

Make sure the `method` is not `null` when you look it up & when you try & pull it from the map, it'll help narrow down the problem

Answer (score 1):

This line can only produce a NPE in case thisResult is null, which in turn means thisKey is not initialized in myTests. Use "aKey" instead of thisKey and it should work.